# Any examples of games in Scala?

Tags: scala

Could you please link to any examples of developing games (featuring 2d graphics and sound) in Scala?

Comment: Are you interested in developing your own game engine, or using someone else's? In making a game for Android, the web, or desktop?

Answer (score 7):

[SCAWAR](http://scalandroid.blogspot.com/) is a realtime Android game written completely in Scala.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly a game, but featuring 2D and some 3D graphics: **Wizbee**, learning software based on the Swiss syllabus ([homepage in French](http://www.wizbee.ch/fr/) or [homepage in German](http://www.wizbee.ch/de/)). There is a demo video that shows some of the graphics [there](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HXChLGHISC4) (also in French).

*Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops this.*

Answer (score 0):

[Googling "games written in scala"](https://www.google.com/search?q=games+written+in+scala) yields results that include:

- [A 2D game engine](http://code.google.com/p/scage/) (NB: Its code style is somewhat idiosyncratic, and the project doesn't use `sbt`.  This may or may not reflect the quality of the library; it's just a mild yellow flag in my eyes.)
- [A relevant previous question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048801/is-there-any-game-engine-in-scala) whose answers point to quite a few excellent resources of the type you seem to be looking for.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: Scala Dice is also scala project written with play framework and akka : http://www.hiddenoctopus.com/sjdice