# Scala-friendly game framework

Tags: scala, game-engine

Is there any finished Scala-friendly 3d game framework with nice documentation and tutorials for beginners?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048801/is-there-any-game-engine-in-scala) question, but it's quite old. Both [Sgine](http://code.google.com/p/sgine/) and [Simplex3d](http://www.simplex3d.org/) don't look alive and/or complete.

Please, do not post answers with Java frameworks/engines if they don't have any kind of Scala support (e.g. custom operators, implicit conversions, tutorials with examples in Scala).

Comment: By the way asking new question with old duplicate is not something that is encouraged on stackoverflow. If you unhappy with existing answers, you may gain attention to that question by [assigning a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any game engine in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048801/is-there-any-game-engine-in-scala)

Comment: I don't think it's the same question. I emphasize the availability of Scala tutorials and easy start for beginners. Also I'm looking for **3d** framework, I'm not looking for any **only-2d** thing as opposed to the old question which hasn't specified what he/she is looking for.

Comment: While the questions is different, you're looking for additional answers which do not seem to exist (unless Google tells you otherwise, but I assume you've done your googling). Hence, the best answer seems this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1050277/53974.

Comment: How about the [scage](https://github.com/dunnololda/scage) ?Maybe libgdx still the best choice ? follow [Using-libgdx-with-Scala](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Scala)

Comment: @wener I'm using libGDX with Scala to develop a simpler game. But not all parts are really Scala friendly, some are even unusable (no support for case classes or collections in JSON serialization and probably more, haven't tried everything libGDX provides) and I'm just writing a 2D game (3D might be entirely different experience).